# How to summarize DateTime-fields in EF6

Tags: entity-framework, linq

again, I'm struggeling with Linq or EF6.

I have a table with columns `(DateTime)[BeginOfWork]` and `(DateTime)[EndOfWork]`.
Now, I need to substract the BeginOfWork-value from the EndOfWork-value. From this result, I need to build a total sum.
In SQL, it looks like this:

```
SELECT Timesheets.EmployeeId, Sum(DateDiff("h",[Timesheets].[BeginOfWork],[Timesheets].[EndOfWork])) AS HoursOfWork
FROM Timesheets
GROUP BY Timesheets.EmployeeId
HAVING (((Timesheets.EmployeeId)=1));
```

How do I do this in EF6?

Actually, not working some variations of that:

```
int employeeId = 1;
var timesheetSum = (from ts in db.Timesheets
    where (ts.EmployeeId == employeeId)
    select new
      {
        hoursOfWork = DbFunctions.DiffHours(ts.BeginOfWork, ts.EndOfWork)
      }).Sum(ts => ts.hoursOfWork);
```

The above results in integer rounded hoursOfWork, that don't include minutes.

So I tried that:

```
var timesheetSum = (from ts in db.Timesheets
    where (ts.EmployeeId == employeeId)
    select new
      {
        hoursOfWork = DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(ts.BeginOfWork, ts.EndOfWork) / 60
       }).Sum(ts => ts.hoursOfWork);
```

But here, hoursOfWork seems to be rounded (integer), so 2,5 hours will result in 2. Perhaps a conversion of the result would work but I don't get it run.

```
`(double)hoursOfWork` results in an error.
```

Perhaps someone has a link to a complete guide, how to convert SQL to Linq-queries.

**SOLUTION**

```
var timesheetSum = (from ts in db.Timesheets
    where (ts.EmployeeId == employeeId && ts.TimesheetDate <= DateTime.Today)
    select new
    {
        hoursOfWork = DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(ts.BeginOfWork, ts.EndOfWork)/60m
     }).Sum(ts => ts.hoursOfWork);

decimal result = 0;
if(timesheetSum!=null)
    result = (decimal)timesheetSum;
```

Thanks a lot

Carsten

Comment: Use [DbFunctions.DateDiffHours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.diffhours?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

Comment: ...updated the post...

Comment: Force `double` or `decimal` calculation, e.g. `/ 60` -> `/ 69d` or `/ 60m`

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'll update my post.